# How to convert cURL request to ajax with curl -d body

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, curl

I'm trying to get the cURL request (working via terminal on my mac) to jQuery ajax, and I'm getting a 400 BAD REQUEST. Please let me know if you see any problems with my code. This is in an attempt to use the Oanda v20 API if that helps.

cURL via terminal (working):

```
body=$(cat << EOF
{
  "order": {
    "units": "100", 
    "instrument": "EUR_USD", 
    "timeInForce": "FOK", 
    "type": "MARKET", 
    "positionFill": "DEFAULT"
  }
}
EOF
)

curl \
  -X POST \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer <AUTHENTICATION TOKEN>" \
  -d "$body" \
  "https://api-fxpractice.oanda.com/v3/accounts/<ACCOUNT>/orders"
```

jQuery ajax (not working):

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'https://api-fxpractice.oanda.com/v3/accounts/' + accountNumber + '/orders',
    data: {
        "order": {
            "units": "10000", 
            "instrument": "EUR_USD", 
            "timeInForce": "FOK", 
            "type": "MARKET", 
            "positionFill": "DEFAULT"
        }
    },
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + auth)
    }, success: function(data){

        console.log(data);

        }
});
```

Obviously, `auth`, `accountNumber`, etc. are valid variables defined outside of this code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The content-type of your request is `application/json`, you should add it to the request and make sure that the content itself is sent as a string (using `JSON.stringify`):

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify({'order': { ... }}),
    ...
});
```

Comment: Oh yeah, that too.

Comment: Yep, I just quickly assumed it was blocked due to trying to send an AJAX request cross-domain.

Comment: Yes, this works. Thank you. Seems to be the combination of these two things updates that fixes the 400.

Answer (score 1):

It might be blocked due to same-origin policy.

Have you tried with JSONP? (add `dataType: "jsonp"` to your ajax call)

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    url: 'https://api-fxpractice.oanda.com/v3/accounts/' + accountNumber + '/orders',
    data: {
        "order": {
            "units": "10000", 
            "instrument": "EUR_USD", 
            "timeInForce": "FOK", 
            "type": "MARKET", 
            "positionFill": "DEFAULT"
        }
    },
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + auth)
    }, success: function(data){

        console.log(data);

        }
});
```

However, given that you're seemingly printing someone's account number into plain text JavaScript on the page, wouldn't it be more secure to send the CURL request from your own php file?  Use Ajax to call your local file and then send the CURL request from there, and use the API's response to formulate your own JSON response to send back to your client side.

Comment: You're right, but this is an application that I am trying to build on client-side languages only. It is for my use only. Basically, I'm just trying to build an app that runs in chrome.